# Can't disable UIButton in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I'm having trouble disabling a UIButton in my UITableViewCell. Code is as follows:

```
func disableAddAudio(reEnable: Bool = false) {

        headerView.recordButton.userInteractionEnabled = reEnable ? true : false
        for index in 0...audioViewModelArray.count - 1 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AddedAudioTableCellReuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)) as! AddedAudioTableCell
            cell.trashButton.userInteractionEnabled = false
        }
    }
```

here if I disable a button in the UITableView header view there are no issues. However the button `trashButton` does not seem to disable even when I set it to false. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: I faced a similar issue when I created a custom UITableViewCell for the first time ..... I guess If you set cell.trashButton.userInteractionEnabled = false in cellForRow it should just work ....

Comment: have you enabled that button in cell for Row ?
Might be issue of cell reusability.

Comment: @Bhavik just checked. Nope. Haven't set enable or disable anywhere else in my code.

Comment: you can either check it by color change or removing that button from superview.
if that will not work then issue is something in tableview Logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)) as! AddedAudioTableCell
cell.trashButton.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: This did it. thank you. My stupidity missing this and using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It will disable the button if it is not nill

cell.trashButton.enabled = false

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this line of code `cell.trashButton.userInteractionEnabled = false` to

```
cell.trashButton.enabled = false
```